# Error in RecyclerViewAdapter's onBindViewHolder() Method ㅠㅠ

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

An error occurred while creating and building the app. Looking at the logcat, it appears that onBindViewHolder() Method has a nullPointerError. But I can't fix it because it hasn't been long since I encountered Android. I saw other questions on this site, but I didn't understand because I don't know English well. I'd appreciate it if you could help me with how to modify it.
Logcat

```
2020-05-25 11:54:53.613 14798-14798/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 1
2020-05-25 11:54:53.632 14798-14798/? E/mple.oryumatzi: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-05-25 11:55:04.170 14798-14798/com.example.oryumatzip E/TAG: OnCreate::
2020-05-25 11:55:04.209 14798-14798/com.example.oryumatzip E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.oryumatzip, PID: 14798
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:29)
        at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:23)
        at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:669)
        at com.example.oryumatzip.CustomAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.java:39)
        at com.example.oryumatzip.CustomAdapter.onBindViewHolder(CustomAdapter.java:17)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:403)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:1011)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26415)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3605)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2348)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2640)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8981)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:996)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:794)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:729)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:981)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
2020-05-25 11:55:04.209 14798-14798/com.example.oryumatzip E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

MyAdapter File

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ListViewItem> arrayList;
    private Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<ListViewItem> arrayList, Context context) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_korean_food, parent, false);
        CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Glide.with(holder.itemView)
                .load(arrayList.get(position).getProfile())
                .into(holder.Iv_profile);
        holder.tv_title.setText(arrayList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.tv_info.setText(arrayList.get(position).getInfo());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (arrayList != null ? arrayList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView Iv_profile;
        TextView tv_title;
        TextView tv_info;


        public CustomViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.Iv_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_profile);
            this.tv_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
            this.tv_info = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_info);
        }
    }
}
```

XML File of RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".KoreanFood"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_koreanFood"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:height="120dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ssflowerroadregular"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="한식"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_koreanFood"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That means that `holder.Iv_profile` is null in the Glide `into()` call, which means that `itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_profile)` is returning null in your `ViewHolder`, which is happening because the `<ImageView>` with ID `iv_profile` is not in that layout. You seem to have inflated the wrong layout in `onCreateViewHolder()`. The `activity_korean_food` layout is apparently for your `Activity`. You want to inflate the one with the `iv_profile` `<ImageView>` and those two `<TextView>`s in it instead.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I fixed it because of your hint!!